# Remove last line from variable string inside the awk script

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I made the following script:

```
awk ' {
  if ($1 ~ /^d/) {
   a=a $0; 
  }
  .... -> rest code
  if (p == 1) {
    b=a;
    print b;
  }
} ' input.txt
```

- a - store found result, I will work later with it so can't change its structure
- b - store part of a, something like header

Input file:

```
      d1file some text
      edont show that
      d2file like it
      d3file need to remove
```

a content at end:

```
      d1file some text
      d2file like it
      d3file need to remove
```

What I would like to do:

If **$1** starts with **d** I store it inside the **a** variable. Later I like to move **a** to **b** and remove last line from **b**, so the output of **b** should be:

```
      d1file some text
      d2file like it
```

I was looking for any solution but no luck at all. I was thinking about store **a** content as array and loop it using index-1 to remove last line, but I couldn't get it worked.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Isn't `dont show that` also starting with `d`?

Comment: Why `a = b`? Why store this all in memory in `a`? What is dropping `dont show that` in your example? If the goal is to print out every matching line but the last there are simpler ways to do that.

Comment: my bad, it should be `edont show that`, changed. @Etan I will work later with `a` and dont what change it.

Comment: No, this is just short example to make an idea of how should it work.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
  /^d/ { a = a $0 "\n"}          # accumulate lines starting with d
  END {
    sub(/\n[^\n]*\n$/, "", a);   # remove the last line
    print a
  }
' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you @ooga, work very well, I was trying arrays at start as JNevill solution says but I like your idea, didnt know that sub() will also work.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
awk 'BEGIN {counter=1} { if ($1 ~ /^d/) array[counter++]=$0} END { for (element=1;element<counter-1;element++) print array[element]}' input.txt
```

This sticks all the search hits in an array, then at the end prints all but the last element of the array

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple `awk` command:

```
awk '$1 ~ /^d/{if(p) a=a p; p=$0 ORS} END{printf a}' input.txt
d1file some text
d2file like it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^d/{a[nr++]=$0}END{for(i=0;i<nr-1;i++) print a[i]}'input.txt
```

`/^d/` selects the lines that start with `d`, and performs the action saves the lines in array `a` if it starts with `d`

The `for` in `END` will print the array exluding the last

Comment: It will print all results until you change `i<nr` for `i<nr-1` or `i=0` for `i=1`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the ultimate goal here and this seems like an odd way to do things but this should do what you want:

```
awk 'tmp{b=b (b?ORS:"") tmp; tmp=""}; /^d/{tmp=$0;next} END{a=b (tmp?ORS:"") tmp; ...do something with a and b here...} input.txt
```

Example:

```
$ cat input.txt
d1file some text
edont show that
d2file like it
d3file need to remove
$ awk 'tmp{b=b (b?ORS:"") tmp; tmp=""}; /^d/{tmp=$0;next} END{a=b (tmp?ORS:"") tmp; print "--"; print a; print "--"; print b; print "--"}' input.txt
--
d1file some text
d2file like it
d3file need to remove
--
d1file some text
d2file like it
--
```